# PHP if else endif and wordpress's loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've a problem with the loop in wordpress, my website is a feed aggregator and basically I want my website to display an image if the feed contains an image or a specified image if it doesn't.
here's the code I actually use:

```
    <?php $enclosure =  get_post_meta($post->ID , 'enclosure', $single = true); ?>
    <?php $image=explode(chr(10),$enclosure); ?>
    <?php if(!is_null($image)) : ?>
    <div class="left">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link all'articolo: <?php     the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="width:150px; text-align:center;"/></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It works very well but now I want to show a "default" image if the feed doesn't provide one, I tried in this way:

```
    <?php $enclosure =  get_post_meta($post->ID , 'enclosure', $single = true); ?>
    <?php $image=explode(chr(10),$enclosure); ?>
    <?php if(!is_null($image)) : ?>
    <div class="left">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link all'articolo: <?php     the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="width:150px; text-align:center;"/></a>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="left">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Link all'articolo: <?php     the_title_attribute(); ?>"><img src="PATH TO THE DEFAULT IMAGE" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" style="width:150px; text-align:center;"/></a>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn't work...
Where am I wrong?
Sorry for my english!

Thanks!

Comment: use empty function instead of is_null,

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need to open and close php tags on every line...

Comment: as @SumitGupta suggest, use `!empty($image)` instead of `!is_null($image)`

Comment: Hi. If a question was answered, you should accept the answer.

Comment: You can put more than one statement inside a php block, do not open and close php blocks for each statement.

Comment: next time, please describe what happens in case of "it doesn't work". Is there an error message, does it look like before, did your computer explode and you're writing this while the emergency drives you to hospital?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(file_exists("file path")){

}
```

instead of

```
`if(!is_null($image)) :`
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
if($image=="" && $image=="null")
{

}
```